# Toshiba sattelite c665 bluetooth not working (Kali)

Tags: kali-linux, bluetooth, toshiba

I have a toshiba sattelite c665 laptop and i have installed kali 1.1.0a few days ago. Bluetooth of my laptop is not working , whenever i click on the bluetooth icon in top bar, it shows "Bluetooth: On" but settings shows that bluetooth is disabled. Following are the outputs of few commands i wrote in terminal and their result,

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0930:0214 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05c6:6001 Qualcomm, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 10f1:1a34 Importek 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)

dmesg | grep Blue
[    1.898797] usb 2-1.6: Product: Askey Bluetooth Module
[    4.933043] toshiba_bluetooth: Detected Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device - installing RFKill handler
[    4.933105] toshiba_bluetooth: Re-enabling Toshiba Bluetooth
[    5.481700] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[    5.481726] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.481737] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.481740] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.481750] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[12298.413361] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[12298.413376] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[12298.413383] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Please help me fix this issue...

Comment: Have you tried to restart the bluetooth service?

Comment: Not restart but start and it failed..

Comment: Can you show us the logs?

Comment: $ /etc/init.d/bluetooth status

[FAIL] bluetooth is not running ... failed!
$ /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop

[ ok ] Stopping bluetooth: rfcomm /usr/sbin/bluetoothd.
$ /etc/init.d/bluetooth start

[ ok ] Starting bluetooth: bluetoothd rfcomm.
$ /etc/init.d/bluetooth status

[FAIL] bluetooth is not running ... failed!

Comment: okay found the problem, i forgot to put sudo before start command, thanks for helping btw